# How to use facebook graph api to get all the current employees of a company?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, scrapy

The new graph search on facebook page allows you to search for current employees of a company by typing a query like "Current Google employees" on the top search bar.

Now how to do the same via Graph API? Or if not possible via Graph API, then I am thinking of scrapping it using say, Scrapy, but then it redirects me to the login.php page. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible via Graph API based on how permissions and privacy in the API work.

I am not rolled out to Graph Search but I'm guessing each query has a specific page and you can use Scrapy to pull it. The reason you are being redirected is because you don't have the proper headers and cookies (such as `dtsg` and `datr`) to see the page. You need Scrapy to impersonate the user of the page.

Though, it wouldn't make sense building an application like this. The whole point of the API is so that you don't scrape pages without their permission. This sounds like a sure way to ask for a cease and desist once you usage is noticable.